# Unsure about performing a calculation with two variables

Tags: java, variables, calculator

This is what I've gotten so far. After the exchange value is calculated at the end I wanted it to charge a commission on whether or not the user is an Account holder or not (asked at the start). Like if they aren't an account holder then there will be a commission of 2% and 1% if they're. I wasn't sure on how to incorporate it into calculating the commission using the AccHolder variable and the ExcAmount. Anyhelp?

```
if (CurChoice.equals("EUR")) {
            result = ExcAmount / Euro;
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            System.out.println(ExcAmount + " in " + CurChoice + "\t=£" + df.format(result));
        } else if (CurChoice.equals("USD")) {
            result = ExcAmount / USAD;
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            System.out.println(ExcAmount + " in " + CurChoice + "\t=£" + df.format(result));
        } else if (CurChoice.equals("JPY")) {
            result = ExcAmount / JapYen;
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            System.out.println(ExcAmount + " in " + CurChoice + "\t=£" + df.format(result));
        } else if (CurChoice.equals("PLN")) {
            result = ExcAmount / Zloty;
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            System.out.println(ExcAmount + " in " + CurChoice + "\t=£" + df.format(result));
        } else {
            System.out.println("");
        }

        double commission = (yn ? 0.01 : 0.02)*result;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        System.out.println("Commission\t=£" + df.format(commission));

        double netPayment = result - commission;
        System.out.println("Total:\t=£" +netPayment);
```

Comment: Your code has a number of unnecessary variables and duplicated lines.  An extended discussion of how to clean it up is beyond the scope of this site but you might want to put it on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare result once.

```
double result = 0.0;
if (CurChoice.equals("EUR")) {
    result = ExcAmount / Euro;
//...
 } else {
    System.out.println("");
}

double commission = (yn ? 0.01 : 0.02)*result;
System.out.println( "commision: " + ... );
double netPayment = result - commission;
```

`yn` is a terrible name, isAccountHolder might be better.

Also, a switch on CurChoice would be preferable to the if.

Comment: `isAcctHldr` is not that much better.

Comment: Even this is not calculating commission as per amount to what OP needs. -1

Comment: Note that my final println says that this includes commission. Probably was thinking of buying, not selling. Sorry.

Comment: 0.01 or 0.02 multiplied with result => commission. result - commission => netPayment.

Comment: I think - sorry for the confusion - it's correct now.

Comment: Edited the code in your question. Wasn't same as my answer.

Comment: Okay I've got it going now. Thanks for all your help. I've probably been the most annoying person you've helped.

Comment: Considering my contribution to the confusion by not seeing that it is buying, not selling: definitely no.

Comment: Lol, thanks for everything. If I had more rep I would upvote like mad but I dont. :D

Answer (score 1):

Where you are defining yn as below:

```
boolean yn;
```

Initialize it with true (as below) as users wont be allowed to enter string other than y/n.

```
boolean yn = true;
```

After reading the amount:

```
int ExcAmount = keybStr.nextInt();
```

Add following lines to calculate the commission to result like:

```
double result = 0.;//default value of result

//do the calculation 

if (yn) {
   result *= 0.01d;
} else { 
   result *= 0.02d;
}
```

And now remove all redeclaration of result like `double result` to just `result`, so we just add converted value to commission.

Comment: Didnt get you. What do you mean by same dimension?

Comment: There we are. retracted the -1

Answer (score 0):

At the end of

```
if (MenuChoice == 1) {
```

you should put this set of conditions:

```
if (yn) ExcAmount += 0.01 * ExcAmount;
else ExcAmount += 0.02 * ExcAmount;
```

This is the conditional you're looking for.

Comment: define "yn" as false and ExcAmount as 0 at the beginning of main()

Comment: That didn't work. It crashed when I select "n" as the account holder. Are you fit to edit the code above so I can see what you mean?

Comment: what was the crash error message when you selected "n"?

Comment: but did it print out a message?